# Excel hyperlink to google sheets not working

Tags: excel

When I click on a hyperlink with gsheet url in excel, **"Update your browser to use Google Drive, Docs, Sheets, Sites, Slides, and Forms"** page opens in browser each time. And when I manually copy paste the link in browser, it works.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to overcome this challenge. Using the Shell command I was able to achieve it. I used VBA to execute the command:

```
Shell "explorer ""https://www.google.com"""
```

This command will open the URL in default browser of user.

Answer (score 1):

It is not caused by malware, it is likely a Windows update that causes Office and Google Docs not to communicate correctly.

See this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/recent-office-updates-breaks-hyperlinks-to-google/cf689f78-bc79-432d-b8ab-a25e956d4a4f) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you cannot click on cell link, you need to hover the cell and after that click on appearing link. That's how links in google sheets work